# How safe is to store a AES encoded password into a file?

Tags: hash, linux, aes, encoding

Basically, I'm considering to store an AES-Base64 encoded password into a hidden file, with a 600 permission, into a uncommon location of a Unix/Linux server.

That password would be used by an automaton in the crontab to connect into others servers.

How bad is this idea? (Considering that the root user is locked, and the servers don't have any access to the internet, and there's a proxy tunneling to connect into the server that will hold this hidden file)

Comment: How does the automaton decrypt the password? Where and how does it store the AES key securely, and why the password can't be stored in the same secure place?

Comment: Can I store the AES key compiled within the automaton, or the AES key must change? If the AES key can be compiled inside the automaton, the automaton could decode the hash and store the key safely.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you *really* need to use passwords? SSH keys would be much more suitable for "an automaton in the crontab to connect into others servers".

If you do need to store such passwords, the proper setup would be creating a specific (non-root) user account for this case, storing the file in a 400 permission file owned by this user, and having the automaton binary run with setuid bit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set to the same account.

I.e., for a normal user account that file would be readable only through that automaton and not by any other means.

I don't think that encryption adds any security there if the storage of encryption key isn't any more secure than storage of the password.

If the automaton is a binary and you include a key there, then you need to ensure that it's executable but not readable. If the automaton is an executable script, then you can't store the key inside it securely at all.

Comment: I really need to use passwords, and there's an user account for this automaton, and the automaton is compiled. But some security policies from the company I work prevent me from store a raw password because other people have access to these servers, so I was thinking to encrypt and store it, almost exactly like you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common challenge and it can be done securely if you are able to accept a number of security tradeoffs in exchange for the benefits of automation. We're doing it all the time anyway, keeping unencrypted TLS private keys on web servers in order to avoid typing passphrase each time when we restart them :) Just use all the available security controls available in a multi-user system, as suggested by Peteris above and I would only add two things:

- Limit the permissions available to these credentials as much as possible on the need-to-know basis, so that they can only perform the automation task and nothing more. Specifically, they shouldn't be able to give access to other systems etc.
- There's a number of vault and password manager like solutions available for Linux but their security model is always based on a single secret entered by the interactive user, so they won't help much here.
- The encryption part will have dubious impact. On one hand, it may prevent an opportunistic thief, but file system permissions would do just as well. On the other hand, they will introduce significant complexity and at the end of the day the encryption key still has to be stored somewhere with protection just as effective as that of the original assets.